# <span> can have width and height?

Tags: html, css

I have a span tag in my markup which i am using for showing a progress indicator. Here is my code

`<span id="load">In Progress...</span>`

```
#load{
/*display: none;*/
text-indent: -9999px;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 10px;
/*width: 45px;
height: 15px;*/
background: url(images/loader.gif);}
```

in above case i don't see my image,when i uncomment the width and height
image shows up thats fine. but since span is inline here and i am not specifying it as inline-block or block in my css how it is taking width and height?

Comment: What size is your GIF file?

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements are treated as blocks.

Comment: Try setting the `background-position` and `background-size`, also I would change `#load` to a class, try to keep ID's to top level elements.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly:Even i removed position and added `float:right`still it works how?

Comment: Because setting a float on an element **also** makes an element a block.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `text-indent: -9999px;` and set width and height for your span tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/wrm8g0gk/

```
#load{
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 10px;
background: url(http://www.xiconeditor.com/image/icons/loading.gif) no-repeat;
height: 55px;
}
```

Comment: That is my question i am wondering how `span` is taking `width`and `height` when it is not supposed to being an inline element.some one said it is because of my positioning but removed absolute position and added float still it works! how?

Comment: @pramodh <span> is an inline element but you are assigning width and height to the span using and ID selector.